# Django channels using RedisPubSubChannelLayer fails to receive

Tags: django, redis, django-channels

I was testing RedisPubSubChannelLayer for a simple send/receive, but the test fails using pytest. (it passes with RedisChannelLayer)

Test class

```
class TestRedis(TestCase):

    # test if RedisChannelLayer communicates
    async def test_channels_send_receive(self):
        channel_name = '45jfngoegnolkmlrmbhrfmh'
        channel_layer = channels.layers.get_channel_layer()
        payload = {'type': 'hello'}
        await channel_layer.send(channel_name, payload)
        print(f"channel_layer.send done")
        result = await channel_layer.receive(channel_name)
        print(f"channel_layer.receive done")
        self.assertEqual(payload, result)
```

Would you help me understand what I'm doing wrong?
If I simply change

```
"BACKEND": "channels_redis.pubsub.RedisPubSubChannelLayer"
```

to

```
"BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer"
```

the test passes, but otherwise, only "channel_layer.send done" prints and hangs on receive

I'm using

- Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
- python 3.10.12,
- redis_version:6.0.16
- channels-redis==4.1.0
- Django==4.2.4
- channels==4.0.0
- pytest==7.4.2
- pytest-asyncio==0.21.1
- pytest-django==4.5.2